# Modifying xml using Java cli

Tags: java, xml, regex, shell

Modifying xml using Java cli. Values in the xml were blank and we pass them from the java code. The file is on a Linux system.The method i am using is  this

```
public String modifySufPlaylist(Cli cli, String file, String[] parms)
        throws RemoteCliException {
    String parmlist = "";

    for (String s : parms) {
        parmlist += " \"" + s + "\"";
    }

    String cmd = "for i in " + parmlist + "; do echo -e \"/<value><\\/value>/\\ns/></>$i</\\nw\\nq\\n\" | ed "
            + file + "; done >/dev/null 2>&1";
    return cli.send(cmd);
}
```

It works fine when My xml has

```
<value></value>
```

Now a few things were changed and the xml looks like this

```
<value>Enter Param 1</value>
<value>Enter IP</value>
<value>Enter password</value>
```

i am stuck on how to modify my script so that is replaces the default value with paramlist values.

Answer (score 0):

Y dont you use [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/PAJAS/XML-XSH2-2.1.6/xsh):

```
for my $file in { glob "*.xml" } {
    open $file ;
    for //SomeTag set @another 'new value' ;
    save :b ;
}
```